# Github organization using secrets, actions and PAT's

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I've created a GitHub organization (and also pay for GitHub enterprise because nothing worked and I became a bit desperate). Note, I'm completely new to Github organization stuff, be kind lol.
What's wrong?
I'm trying to push local changes to GitHub, which should trigger a deploy to DigitalOcean here is the link to the .yml file ().
So far so good, but at the end of the build, ssh-login part it says:

**"Error response from daemon: unauthorized: Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured."**

In my terminal I do get the same error with:

```
docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u <UserName> -p <GitHub Personal Access Token>

docker pull docker.pkg.github.com/quanttrade-io/quanttrade-api/quanttrade-api:latest
```

And I've also tried:

```
docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u <Organization name> -p <GitHub Personal Access Token>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it thanks to this article: https://github.community/t/personal-access-token-deleting-itself/13955

I hard coded the PAT in my .yml file, so Github deleted it automatically.
Now it works!